# jQuery custom slider

Tags: jquery, slider

I have a slider from one online tutorial:
http://jsfiddle.net/RXpjM/

The good thing is that I understand that code (how it works etc.).
The problem is that now I want to change the "going back to the beginning" option. As you can see now it just slide from the last (image4) to the first one (image1), but it shows all others images (it goes from right to the left). I want it to simply go from image4 to image1, just like there was another image after image4.

Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: One way to do it is to add a copy of the first image to the end of all  the floating images. When switching from last (the previously last) to first, you first slide to the new last (the copy of the first) and then when the sliding has stopped you can change to the first (without animation). I've seen this approach in some sliders and i think it's the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is normally called as `Carousel`

**Example**: http://jsfiddle.net/zCe3j/3/

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want to achieve